# Why is this block of code populating the 13th element of the array with a 0?

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++, apologies if this question is below the community's paygrade.

I don't quite understand what is causing this block of code to populate every 13th element of the array with a 0.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include "_pause.h"

using namespace std;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               NOTE
// This is your program entry point. Your main logic is placed
// inside this function. You may add your functions before this
// "main()", or after this "main()" provided you added reference
// before this "main()" function.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    
    int count = 1;
    int seat[5][7];
    int ctr, ctr2;
    bool cont=true;
    char choice[3];
    do
    {
        for(int ctr=0;ctr<5;ctr++)
        {
            for(int ctr2=0;ctr2<7;ctr2++)
            {
                if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)
                {
                    seat[ctr][ctr2]=count;
                }
                count++;
                cout<<seat[ctr][ctr2]<<"\t";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Do you want to continue (Y/N)?";
        cin>>choice;
        if (choice=="Y" || choice=="YES")
        {
            cont=true;
        } else (cont==false);
    } while (cont=true);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the variables look like by the 14th loop:

[variable watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdxgS.png)

Appreciate the hints, and apologies if this is a really basic question. I'm still struggling to wrap my head around the concepts.

Comment: I see arrays of length 5, 7, and 3. Which of these is supposed to have a 13th element?

Comment: I don't think `if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)` does what you think it does.

Comment: @JaMiT  If you look at the screenshot that he links to, it shows that seat[1][5] = 0

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Why should I look at a screenshot to get textual information? I'm also not clear on why there would be a variable watch instead of the program's output.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my question is. Seat numbers should be populating based on the "count" variable and I've never seen it drop to 0 during debugging.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour.  You don't initialize the seat array to anything and then `if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)` reads the value of `seat[ctr][ctr2]`, does a bitwise or  with 0 and assigns the value back to `seat[ctr][ctr2]`.  You can not read the value of an uninitialized array value.  Anyway, the upshot is that `seat[ctr][ctr2]=count;` happens inside an if statement that isn't always true.

Comment: Mentioning the aim of this block of code would be useful.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur.

Comment: @JaMiT  Your first comment wasn't useful - if you wanted a textual version of the screenshot then you could have just asked for one instead of asking a rhetorical question that doesn't hint at your real intention.

Comment: @JaMiT I might have used the wrong term. "seat" is supposed to be a two-dimensional array with 5 rows and 7 columns that supposed to take values of 1 through 35. I'm noticing that every 13th value is being populated by a 0 although the "count" variable still seems to be taking values incrementally.

Comment: Why is `seat[ctr][ctr2]=count;` inside an if statement if you need to initialize all the values anyway.  And what did you really mean with `if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)` since you probably didn't mean to do a bitwise or with an uninitialised value?

Comment: Hey @PalLaden, the aim of this is to initialize the entire array with incremental values from 1 to 35.

Comment: Ahhh.  I know what's wrong.  You said "and I've never seen it drop to 0 during debugging" - that's the secret.  During debugging the VS compiler probably clears all the array values to a known value.  But that doesn't happen when you aren't debugging.  You really do need to initialise the array.  Try `int seat[5][7]={};` instead of `int seat[5][7];`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, this is just part of the exercise I'm working on. The next work item is a block of code that reserves seats with a "0" based on user input. The goal was to throw an error message stating that a seat is reserved if its value is 0.

Comment: If the aim of this is to initialize the entire array with incremental values from 1 to 35 then remove the if statement altogether.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed. Initializing the entire array with 1's did the trick.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I did not know the image was a screenshot until you informed my of the fact. Please do not assume that people both are willing to follow spurious links. Questions must be self-contained. Following links is optional.

Comment: @儚き戦士の翼 A better way to express that intent: *"This code iterates over the elements of the 2-dimensional array `seat`. Every thirteenth element found is being populated with a 0, and I do not understand why."* There are several supporting changes to the wording. The key difference is changing "thirteenth element of the array" to "thirteenth element found (by the loop)".

Answer (score 1):

The array `seat[5][7]` is not initialized. This causes undefined behavior. It looks like the undefined behavior in this case is that it is initialized to something like:

```
int seat[5][7] = {
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
};
```

When initialized this way, your code would reliably experience the output that you are seeing.

https://repl.it/repls/EnchantingUncommonOrders#main.cpp

#### As an aside..

```
if (seat[ctr][ctr2] |= 0) {
  seat[ctr][ctr2] = count;
}
```

is functionally the same as

```
if (seat[ctr][ctr2] != 0) {
  seat[ctr][ctr2] = count;
}
```

So if the seat array has any value initialized to zero, your code will not update that slot.

Comment: Thanks Bill, initializing the array with 1's produced the behavior I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

running this code prints out your uninitialized array before filling it with the count:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include "_pause.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    int count = 1;
    int seat[5][7];

    char choice[3];
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<5;ctr++)
    {
        for(int ctr2=0;ctr2<7;ctr2++)
        {
            cout << seat[ctr][ctr2] << "\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    
    for(int ctr=0;ctr<5;ctr++)
    {
        for(int ctr2=0;ctr2<7;ctr2++)
        {
            //cout << seat[ctr][ctr2] << "\t";
            if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)
            {
                seat[ctr][ctr2]=count;
            }
            count++;
            cout<<seat[ctr][ctr2]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
4198544 0   665174296   32570   -1567184848 32766   1   
0   -1567184848 32766   4210104 0   2   0   
4199279 0   72703   0   65535   1   -1567184832 
32766   4199301 0   2   0   4199381 0   
670623024   32570   0   0   4199312 0   4198560 


1   0   3   4   5   6   7   
0   9   10  11  0   13  0   
15  0   17  0   19  20  21  
22  23  0   25  0   27  0   
29  30  0   0   33  0   35
```

You'll notice anywhere the uninitialized value is zero, the set value is zero, otherwise, you get count. The Array is not initialized, so values are arbitrarily set.

A few other things that seem wrong:

this line is unnecessary, as these variables will be declared in the for loop
`int ctr, ctr2;`
This line seems like it doesn't do what you think it is supposed to do:

```
if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)
```

This sets the value in the array to the bitwise or of itself and 0. It will evaluate to true only if the uninitialized value was not 0 (as only 0|0 will be 0), which is why you have some elements in your 2D array set to zero. Also, was this your homework assignment?

Comment: Thanks @fishrec, yes it is. We're supposed to code a rudimentary seat reservation system that reserves seats based on user input, a 0 would mean that a seat is reserved. My first order of business was to display the array. I meant to use ```if(seat[ctr][ctr2]|=0)``` to test the reservation status of the seat.